# Error sending result RpcResponse / closing connection - Datastax Enterprise

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am running a Scala application via Maven and it uses spark-submit to send a fat-jar from a client node to a Datastax Enterprise cluster. (on Azure).

Eveerything seems to be running fine, it does submit the job to the Spark Worker/Master but at some point it starts throwing this lot continually and never exits:

```
[rpc-server-17-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler - Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=6159268836916637242, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=47 cap=64]}} to /10.0.0.4:40852; closing connection
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:810)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1081)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1128)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

All the dependencies are downloaded normally no problem with the compilation. I have the following in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
<artifactId>dse-spark-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>6.7.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
<artifactId>dse-byos_2.11</artifactId>
<version>6.7.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<exclusions><exclusion>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>  
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-connector</artifactId>
<version>6.7.1</version>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
<artifactId>java-driver-core-shaded</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!--<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
<version>4.1.25.4.dse</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
<version>4.1.25.Final</version>
<classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency> -->
```

Also, I tried , based on this https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/faq/ to pass that parameter to use FORCE_NIO, but it does not make any difference at all.

I have even tried running the app like:

`dse -u cassandra -p pass spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$(dse spark-classpath)" --class my.package.bde.TestSparkApp target/big-data-engine-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dcom.datastax.driver.FORCE_NIO=true`  but throws a different error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build has really incorrect dependencies as it was pointed in previous answer. You need to leave only

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
<artifactId>dse-spark-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>6.7.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and remove everything else - byos, spark-connector, netty, java-driver-core, etc.

Comment: right. but that would only be if i were to execute (spark-submit) the jar locally on the Master node....right? because otherwise it failed .. . but i will try it now ..Thanks!

Comment: You are THE man mate! THANK YOU ! It worked from the client node via dse spark-submit with :  dse -u cassandra -p password spark-submit --master dse://10.0.0.4 --class my.package.bde.TestSparkApp target/big-data-engine-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dcom.datastax.driver.FORCE_NIO=true (which I pressume this FORCE_NIO) could possibly be removed too I guess..

Comment: also, please don't use `cassandra` user - follow instructions here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/Auth/secCreateRootAccount.html